# Creating array in jQuery and adding/removing elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an input field:

```
<input type="text" value="hello1,hello2" id="list">
```

I want to grab this value and turn it into an array (guessing `.split()` is the appropriate way):

```
var list = $('#list').val().split(",");
```

Now. How do I add *add* and element to this array? And how do I unset an array element? For example:

```
if (array_element == 'hello1') {
   // unset array_element
}
```

Comment: **Add** Concatenate the value. **Remove** Get value, split, filter, join, set value.

Comment: @Tushar Please post an answer with code examples. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an item:

`list.push('hello3');`

Remove an item:

```
list.splice( $.inArray('hello1',list) ,1 );
```